# Custom DomPDF names

Tags: php, dompdf

I can render a DomPDF file with the following line :

```
$dompdf->stream($fileNo.$name.$description.".pdf");
```

It outputs a pdf that looks like : 121CharlesLakeHome.pdf

How would I put a dash in there to make it look like this : 121-Charles-LakeHome.pdf

I have tried this :

```
$dompdf->stream($fileNo."-"$name."-"$description.".pdf");
```

No Workie.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: you got syntax error. You forgot dot(point) '.'  in string `$dompdf->stream($fileNo."-"$name."-"$description.".pdf");` should be the `$dompdf->stream($fileNo."-".$name."-".$description.".pdf");`

Comment: @Naumov That was exactly it, Thanks!  How can I select this as an answer?

Comment: I posting this comment as answer. You can edit my answer, because I bad speak English.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

got syntax error. You forgot dot(point) '.' in string `$dompdf->stream($fileNo."-"$name."-"$description.".pdf");`
 should be this 
`$dompdf->stream($fileNo."-".$name."-".$description.".pdf");`

Comment: Thanks, did not realize the "." had to be before and after the variables.  Learning php slowly but surely :D

Comment: @Steven Is fine in begin.